# ssh into ubuntu server gives "bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1" every time

Tags: server, 20.04, ssh

I have a machine set up that runs Ubuntu Desktop. I use it as a server mostly so most of the time I just ssh into it.
Recently after running a docker gaming server, when I ssh into my machine, this message pops up every time

```
bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
```

and it seems to be accurate becasue if I "Ctrl+C" then I get my CLI but in order to close the connection, I have to use ~. because using "exit" just shows another line. Why am I stuck in an ssh loop?
I am sshing in to Ubuntu 20.04 from windows 10

Comment: Do you have a recursive call to `~/.bashrc` in `~/.bashrc`? Check with `bash -x ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @waltinator good call. Had newgrp docker in my bashrc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`newgrp` starts a new shell (which sources `~/.bashrc`, which calls `newgrp`), and around we go.

An easier way to add oneself to the `docker` group is:

```
sudo adduser $USER docker
```

Which will take effect at your next login.

Comment: I appreciate it. Should've manned what it does before using it